# Why do linewidths (lwd) less than 1 not differ in plots produced by postscript or pdf drivers in R?

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, postscript

The code below produces varying line widths in png, but the same apparent line widths in both `postscript` and `pdf` devices. This occurs with pdfs viewed in OS X 10.10, but produced under either that OS or in Ubuntu. (Three sample images below)

I found an [unhelpful thread on r-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/071752.html) which suggests this shouldn't be a problem. But it is.

Why?

```
devices <- list(png=png,
        eps=function(...) postscript(..., horizontal=TRUE),
        pdf=pdf)

for(d in names(devices)){
  devices[[d]](file=paste0('test.', d))

  par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
  for (LW in c(0.05, 0.1, .25, .5)){
    plot(height ~ age, data=Loblolly, pch='')
    for(sd in unique(Loblolly$Seed))
      lines(height ~ age, data = subset(Loblolly, Seed == sd), lwd = LW)
    title(LW)
  }
  dev.off()
}
```

#### Pdf on os x 10.10, R 3.2.3

[image: Pdf on os x 10.10, R 3.2.3]

#### Pdf on ubuntu, R 3.2.4

[image: Pdf on ubuntu, R 3.2.4]

#### Eps on ubuntu, R 3.2.4

[image: Eps on ubuntu, R 3.2.4]

Comment: You need to open those with a capable pdf viewer and zoom in on them. There is variation. OSX 10.11 R 3.2.4. Preview. I'm torn between downvoting for failing to adequately investigating the problem and making false claims, versus upvoting for providing good code. I guess like American football: offsetting penalties.

Comment: thanks. you're right. the degree of variation just varies between viewers. ugh

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as user 42- pointed out, is that they do vary.

These differences are just not apparent at some zoom levels, on some monitors, or with some eyeballs. They also may be much less apparent than in bitmap formats (e.g., png) where apparent width is consistent across zoom levels.

For example, in OS X 10.10 at 300ish zoom in Preview [image: 300ish zoom in preview shows differences]

Compare in the same viewer at Actual Size
[image: actual size shows no differences]

Comment: The reason I'm not upvoting your useful answer is that I thought to OP might want to delete it and upvoting your answer would have prevented deletion.

Comment: @42- thanks for that consideration. it did turn out to be a bit silly. but I think it's be worth leaving for two reasons: that r-help thread is out there but isn't useful, also these same lwd differences are much more apparent in bitmap formats

Comment: one strategy that i've taken when using `spplot()` with `png()`, which doesn't seem to respond to `lwd<1` (though `spplot` does respond to `lwd>1`), is to just increase the size of the graphics device via `png(width, height)`. this increases the sizes of the polygons without changing the `lwd`, hence the lines look thinner (and can always post process the image later).